# Unresponsive jQuery on divs

Tags: jquery, html, button, opacity

I have run into a few problems with jQuery. I have learnt HTML and CSS and now am experimenting with making divs affect divs.

I have the following in my HTML doc.

```
<div id="MinecraftVideo">
<iframe width="630" height="350" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/MmB9b5njVbA" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen id="Minecraft"></iframe>
</div>

<img src="../Images/film_icon.png" id="picture_on">

<script> 

$(document).ready(function(){
$(“#picture_on”).click(function(){
$(“#MinecraftVideo”).animate({
opacity: '0.5'
    });
  });
});

</script>
```

I want to be able to click on the picture with the id="film_on" to make the movie id="MinecraftVideo" go to 50% transparency.

I have tried the above code but the picture/button remains unresponsive. Could you please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well here working code, check it here.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#picture_on').click(function() {
    $('#MinecraftVideo,#picture_on').animate({
      opacity: '0.5'
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="MinecraftVideo">
  <iframe width="630" height="350" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/MmB9b5njVbA" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen id="Minecraft"></iframe>
</div>

<img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-zNG-B0kXgRQ/U--a1LM-krI/AAAAAAAAFZk/S3pk18znFdY/s400-c/Best-Games.jpg" id="picture_on">
```

Comment: How curious... It's good to know the code works in the above snippet. Wonder why it isn't working in the page itself ...thanks for checking it for me

Comment: @JamesNovis please mark answers as right. Please check all your questions. Marking answers is why others help ya. And its just a "must" to mark them as right. Other users will be afraid if you don't do this. Think, they invested some time to help ya, so please mark right answers... ?

Comment: @JamesNovis you did the same to me here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30544686/javascript-image-as-a-button

Comment: Hi, I can see that the code is correct. However when I test the webpage by loading it up from my desktop in Chrome or IE the video does not change when I click on the video.

Comment: I have checked to see that javascript is enabled in both IE and chrome. Part of the question was why it was unresponsive. As soon as it has been answered I will mark the right answer.