# JavaScript image as a button (onClick)

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, button

I'm having a little problem with JavaScript and wondered whether you could help me. I have an image and a video. I want to be able to click the image and to make the video at half transparency. I can't quite see why my code doesn't work.

#### Image

```
<img src="James Outlined.jpg" id="picture_on">
```

#### iFrame

```
<iframe width="630" height="350" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/MmB9b5njVbA" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen id="MinecraftVideo"></iframe>
```

#### JavaScript code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(“#picture_on”).click(function(){
    $(“#MinecraftVideo”).animate({
    opacity: '0.5'
        });
      });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: have you got any error??

Comment: Don't use Multibyte characters as delimiter. Change `”` to `"`.

Comment: Code is okay: http://jsfiddle.net/72urv0t4/

Comment: Code is not okey, cause its not valide! Check the delimiters.

Comment: I am running the html doc containing the code, in chrome. However, when I click on the pic, there is no change to the transparency of the video.

Comment: @JamesNovis I added my "hint" as an answer. It will work for you. Cheers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have some JavaScript syntax error's in your codes.

> $(“#picture_on”)

Don't use [multibyte characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) as delimiters. Change `”` to `"` or `'`. Until using the right syntax, your code is working fine. Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ouLha5nj/).

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#picture_on").click(function(){
        $("#MinecraftVideo").animate({
            opacity: '0.5'
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**JavaScript image as a button:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#picture_on").click(function(){
            $("#MinecraftVideo").animate({
                opacity: '0.5'
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```